# How to add a universal form submit handler to ALL forms?

Tags: 7, forms

Suppose i need to record all form submissions in a site, i mean all of them.
I would add a new submit handler to be executed after each forms submit handler, like `$form['#submit'][] = 'log_submit'` , right?

The problem is that some forms may not have the submit handler inside `$form['#submit']` array but in $form['buttons'] or $form['#actions'] etc...

How would i add my own submit handler to ALL of these forms, in one hook_form_alter() and in a clean way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) without traditional `if` inside. Then it'll work on all forms.

Problems start when submit handlers are attached not to form, but to buttons. If you have to take care about that, you will need to scan recursively form tree, find all elements with `['#submit']` set and attach your handler to them. to do this, write recursive* function. Drupal mixes properties with children elements, so to avoid scanning properties, use [element_children(&$elements, $sort = FALSE)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/element_children/7).

*Of course you can make it iterative, too, should be faster, but recursion is more intuitive approach.

Comment: @PanChrono and would you mind telling us *why*? Maybe there is cleaner solution for what's your desired end result.

Comment: As stated above i want to log each forms submission, previous values - submitted values, another question would be how to test that...

Comment: @PanChrono I meant why do you need to log all that. If, for example, for HTTP testing purposes, it might be better to let Ettercap sniff your (or server's) LAN. Many forms, like Search or Views exposed filters hardly makes sense to log on their own, but will generate a lot of noise.